# Why does my topic text ("Learn Elementary Math") pushed to the left?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(48, 176, 235); /*The background color of the page*/
  color: rgb(199, 195, 195); /*The color of the words*/
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; /*The font family of the website*/
}

header{
  font-size: 30px; /*The font size of the header*/
  text-align: center; /* The alignment of the title, Prodigies*/
}

h1 {
  background-color: rgb(30, 109, 255); /*The background color of the header*/
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
}

footer h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
} 

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {

}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  line-height: 90px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: silver;
}

ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

ul li:hover ul{
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

ul li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(15, 98, 253, 0.2);
}

.topic-text{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: rgb(238, 237, 237);
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.7s; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
    <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
        </li> 
        <li>
          <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
        </li>
        <li>

          <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href = "" >About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href = "" >Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href = "" >Credits</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <header>
      <h1>
        PRODIGIES
        <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/>
      </h1>
    </header>

    
    <div class = "topic-text">
      <p>
        Learn Elementary Math.
      </p>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

The text where it says "Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies" is supposed to be centered, but a transition I made keeps pushing it to the right.

I don't know how to put the text centered. Please Help!

**I'm thinking the transition has something to do with my situation.**

Comment: make your example reproducible please.

Comment: Try using normalize.css instead of reset.

Comment: Your code is working fine and its centered for me.
Explain more please you just add your whole project?
Only share your problem man or once elo not in every situation.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: I did share my problem

Comment: Listen, my problem is the text ("Learn Elementary Math") is supposed to be just centered, but it gets pushed to the left. I don't know why. Do you understand now?

Comment: You can see this in the Home section.

Comment: Now, can you please answer my question?

Comment: @KidProgrammer
I don't know how to say, Dude its centered look:
https://pasteboard.co/JjjLkAq.png
Thats what i see.

Comment: Well it's not centered for me

Comment: @KidProgrammer
So tell me, At which size you face this problem?
What browser do you use?

Comment: Google. I just open the file there.

Comment: Make sure you closed every div tags and did you used !important property?
apply it on your text-align and mention me if changed or not.

Comment: nothings works!

Comment: You using Chrome or Firefox or what?

Comment: Also adding to @sergeykuznetsov comment, Consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in Chrome, Firefox and Internet explorer and was centered in every size.
could you please use your snippet?
and make a verdict for me?
i mean take a screenshot of your inspect then i can help much better.
but i guess you forgot to close your div or simple problems...
if `text-align` is not working fine look at this link:
[https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp#:~:text=Center%20Align%20Elements,the%20edges%20of%20its%20container](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp#:%7E:text=Center%20Align%20Elements,the%20edges%20of%20its%20container).

try to use `margin: auto;`
`width: 50%;`

Comment: I Took a screenshot:

Comment: file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202020-07-25%20at%2012.22.09%20PM.png

Comment: @KidProgrammer
I edited my answer and try to add those styles please.
and upload your screenshot to a host server not local.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on using CSS Grid and Flebox, they make alignment and positioning much easier than using floats, fixed widths, and margins.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout for a more in depth guide. Example:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-column-gap: 12px;
  grid-row-gap: 12px;
}
.grid-item-1 {
  grid-column: 1/span 6;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here you're creating a grid, and telling `grid-item-1` to consume all the columns, and align to the start, and vertical align to middle. Play with these concepts to build the layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your question need improvment but its better to use.

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
```

and

```
width:50%
```